# Erratic script performance in Google sheets script

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, delay

I have a series of spreadsheets that manages a golf league. When the scorer has entered scores in a Scores Book a script posts the scores by marking the sheet as available. Another book imports available scores and attempts to produce a PDF. From time to time, the script does not finish before it runs out of execution time and when that happens and an execution transcript is available, there are different points where extensive amounts of time are used in what appear to be trivial steps. Here is an example

[17-08-03 08:20:15:893 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.openById([1T6-EVpw0GH_oP-kjuJUnezhzgLOQPGU-QgTkuBD8Nog]) [0.15 seconds]

[17-08-03 08:20:15:944 PDT] Spreadsheet.getName() [0.051 seconds]

[17-08-03 08:20:15:945 PDT] Logger.log([System book is: Gaffers - System (2017), []]) [0 seconds]

[17-08-03 08:20:15:946 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([Week Results]) [0 seconds]

[17-08-03 08:21:27:748 PDT] Sheet.hideRows([2, 4]) [71.801 seconds]

[17-08-03 08:21:27:749 PDT] Sheet.clearNotes() [0 seconds]

[17-08-03 08:22:57:737 PDT] Sheet.getRange([A3]) [89.987 seconds]

[17-08-03 08:22:57:807 PDT] Executi

---

When the problem occurs, and a transcript is available, the point of the excessive times does not appear to be consistent.

Can anyone advise what might be causing these kinds of delays?

FYI: My structure is set up this way because if the poor scorer tries to enter hole-by-hole scores for multiple players on a sheet with all the calculations in it, there is a substantial delay before keyboard entries seem to be accepted. When it was originally built in Excel, calculations could be turned off to avoid that issue.

Comment: Post your code. You seem to be using a lot of [ ] where do don't need to/ shouldn't be using square brackets.

Comment: If you get rid of the in cell functions and do everything with scripts then you can turn off the calculations by running the functions later.

Comment: @JamesDonnellan - thanks James - that is not my code, but the text provided by the Execution transcript. I do not have any square brackets in my code.

Comment: @Cooper - an interesting thought

Comment: I also have this same issue, simple things that usually take 0 seconds take either 10 or 20 seconds (setTabColor for example). Copying the sheet to a new sheet makes it fast again with the same scripts backing it.